# Error while adding Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-analytics-firebase

I tried to add Google Analytics v4.0 via Google Play Services to my android project.

The compiler shows an error in global_tracker.xml and says:

```
...
<screenName name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.samples.mobileplayground.ScreenviewFragment">
        AnalyticsSampleApp ScreenViewSampleScreen
</screenName>
...
```

**Error: Found tag screenName where item is expected**

Answer (score 16):

Found the problem:

global_tracker.xml was copied to **res/values** folder, while should be copied to **res/xml** folder

Comment: Be careful when selecting new file in Eclipse as it will automatically select "LinearLayout" and create the file under the layouts directory.